# How to keep leading zeros when opening CSV file in VBA

Tags: vba, csv

I have a VBA code that quickly transfer data from CSV files, but unfortunately exclude leading zeros (For example 000123 is converted to 123)

```
Filename = "c:\text.csv"
Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
Dim wsI As Worksheet
Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Temp")
Filename = "c:\text.csv"

Set wbO = Workbooks.Open(Filename) 
wbO.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wsI.Cells
wbO.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I have tried to add the following after opening the csv file > Cells.NumberFormat = "@"

```
Set wbO = Workbooks.Open(Filename) 
Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
wbO.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wsI.Cells
wbO.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Unfortunately, it is not working and the problem I see is that once the file opens already is missing the leading zeros

Is it possible to open the file without affecting the leading zeros and show all the data as text to maintain the leading zeros?

Comment: Do you know how many columns the csv file will have? Does it all the time have the same number of columns? Is it of `TabDelimited` type?

Comment: It is coma delimited. It has 29 columns and the number of columns will not change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub testOpenWithLZeroTxt()
 Dim Filename As String, wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook, wsI As Worksheet
 Dim arrTXT, nrCol As Long, arr(), i As Long, sep As String, lineSep As String
 Dim allTxt As String, txtStr As Object, fileTxt As String, fs As Object, f As Object, ts As Object
 
 Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
 Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Temp")
 Filename = "c:\text.csv"
    fileTxt = Split(Filename, ".")(0) & ".txt" 'create a helper txt file using the csv string content
    
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    allTxt = fs.OpenTextFile(Filename, 1).ReadAll 'reed the csv file content
    fs.CreateTextFile fileTxt
    Set f = fs.GetFile(fileTxt)
    Set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(2, -2)
        ts.write allTxt                          'write the csv content in a newly created txt file
    ts.Close
    
    'Check the number of text file columns:_______
    sep = vbLf ' if not working you can try vbCrLf. It works so on your file
    lineSep = ","  'it my be vbTab, ";" etc. It works so on your file
    arrTXT = Split(allTxt, sep)
    nrCol = UBound(Split(arrTXT(0), lineSep))
    '_____________________________________________
    
    ReDim arr(nrCol) 'redim the format array
    For i = 0 To nrCol
        arr(i) = Array(i + 1, 2) 'fill the format array with variant for TEXT Format!
    Next
    'open the helper txt file as you need:
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fileTxt, origin:=437, startRow:=1, _
                DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=False, Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=arr()
    Set wbO = ActiveWorkbook
    'wbO.Sheets(1).cells.Copy wsI.Range("A1") 'copy the content
    wbO.Close SaveChanges:=False              'close the file
    Kill fileTxt                              'kill helper txt file
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

I changed the code philosophy. It will firstly read the csv content in a string variable and create a txt file using the obtained string and open it as text, which certainly should work. It will work for any number of columns in the csv file.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. It is still being copied as numeric and the leading zeros disappear. If I stop the process where the csv file opens,  I can see already in that in the source file is missing the leading zeros. The leading zeros definitely exist as if I open the file with notepad I can see them.

Comment: @Selrac: This may happen only because you did not tell me **which is the delimiter** and also the line ending delimiter... Is it a CSV comma separated type? The above code, **as I said**, works for such a type. If not working, please change the `sep` variable from `vbLf` to `vbCrLf`... There are two dedicated variables to change the above mentioned delimiters: `sep` and `lineSep`.

Comment: It is comma separated (like 1131905040,00384289275004753375). I tried changing to sep = vbCrLf but didn't make a difference

Comment: @Selrac: If not something confidential, can you share the csv file in discussion? If yes, you can use [this](https://easyupload.io/) transfer site. It is free and easy to be used... In the meantime, plese test the adapted code, which does not calculate the columns number, any more. It works for 29 columns.

Comment: OK. I will look at it and come back with a solution...

Comment: @Selrac: I made some short tests and the file is, indeed comma separated and `vbLf` works like lines separator. I cannot understand why it is not open as text, but no time now to check more. I must leave home in some minutes and I took your question like a challenge. I will adapt the code to read the csv content, to place it in a text file and then open it as you need. Finally, the helping file will be deleted. I will look deeper ai it when I will have enough time to investigate...

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru, your code works well actually, I understand that you create an array of (n,2) to format the column as text. Clever! There is a column set as "xxx,xxx" which is also picked as a whole field (instead of 2 separate columns). Well done

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru , great workaround to a sticky issue

Answer (score 3):

The line break in your csv file is unix LF. This corresponds to chr(10).

Since the number of columns in the first row and the number of columns in the next row are inconsistent, a little bias was used. An array was created by doubling the number of columns in the first row.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Fn As String
    Dim Arr As Variant
    
    Fn = "Example.csv"
    'Fn = "c:\text.csv"
    Set Ws = Sheets("Temp")
    
    Arr = getDatFromCsv(Fn)
    
    With Ws
        .Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells = Empty
        .Range("a1").Resize(UBound(Arr, 1) + 1, UBound(Arr, 2) + 1) = Arr
    End With
    
    
End Sub
Function getDatFromCsv(strFn As String) As Variant
    Dim vR() As String
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, j As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim objStream  As Object
    Dim strRead As String
    Dim vSplit, vRow
    Dim s As String
    
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    With objStream
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile strFn
         strRead = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
    
    vSplit = Split(strRead, Chr(10)) 'Unix Lf ~~> chr(10)
    r = UBound(vSplit)
    c = UBound(Split(vSplit(0), ",", , vbTextCompare))
    ReDim vR(0 To r, 0 To c * 2)
    
    For i = 0 To r
        vRow = Split(vSplit(i), ",", , vbTextCompare)
        'If UBound(vRow) = c Then 'if it is empty line, skip it
            
            For j = 0 To UBound(vRow)
                vR(i, j) = vRow(j)
            Next j
        'End If
    Next i
    getDatFromCsv = vR
    
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```

### Result Image

[image]

Comment: The code fails in this line: ".Range("a1").Resize(UBound(Arr, 1) + 1, UBound(Arr, 2) + 1) = Arr" witn the error 'runtime error 1004 Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: That worked, thanks!! I don't understand what your code is exactly doing, but it is great.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OpenText method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) instead.

The most important parameter is `FieldInfo`. You need to pass:

> *an array containing parse information for individual columns of data. The interpretation depends on the value of DataType. When the data is delimited, this argument is an array of two-element arrays, with each two-element array specifying the conversion options for a particular column. The first element is the column number (1-based), and the second element is one of the [XlColumnDataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype) constants specifying how the column is parsed*.

In other words, every column with leading zeros, has to be defined as `xlTextFormat`.

I'd suggest to record macro. ;) An option to load text data, you'll find under `Data` tab -> ... -> `From text/CSV`

Comment: I tried with the OpenText and fileInfo, but couldn't get it to work

Comment: From the answer from @FaneDuru I can see that you were right. FaneDuru solution it is useful as it identifies the number of columns so that to create an array to define all columns with the format (n,2) for the FieldInfo.